# angular bootstrap older versions removed from npmjs?

Tags: npm, angular-bootstrap

We had been using version 0.11.0 of angular-bootstrap from npmjs. It appears that version is no longer available on npmjs. From the commands below does this mean that someone actually  unpublished the older packages?

```
prompt:~$ npm view angular-bootstrap time

{ modified: '2015-01-12T06:48:54.881Z',
  created: '2014-01-29T21:54:32.213Z',
  '0.0.1': '2014-01-29T21:54:37.589Z',
  '0.0.2': '2014-01-29T22:03:08.814Z',
  '0.0.3': '2014-01-29T22:51:49.998Z',
  '0.0.4': '2014-02-11T15:14:17.078Z',
  '0.11.0': '2014-06-24T07:06:56.435Z',
  '0.13.0-SNAPSHOT': '2014-12-02T13:05:43.151Z',
  '0.12.0': '2015-01-12T06:46:41.986Z' }

prompt:~$ npm view angular-bootstrap versions
0.12.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ticket discussing this and the future is at https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1636

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the package seems to have been unpublished.  You can still access it from the github history, as follows:

`$ npm install "angular-ui/bootstrap#0.11.0"`

(note that you may not need quoting, but some shells will interpret the `#` as a comment-begin character.)  You can also use this syntax in `dependencies` inside `package.json`

If you have a project in production that depends on this, you should probably make a fork of the angular-ui/bootstrap repository and point towards that.

(I had some difficulty making this work on Windows, but it looks like you're on a Unixy system, so you should be fine.)